# Slim4 PUT and DELETE not recognized when called in the browser

Tags: slim, put, http-delete

*According to the documentation https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v2/routing/put.html and https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/middleware/method-overriding.html I can mimic PUT or DELETE request in Slim4 by adding _method input and by adding Method Overriding Middleware
after the routing middleware. For some reason Chrome does not cooperate with me.

So here is my code:

**routes.php:**

```
$app->get('/dashboard', \App\Action\Dashboard::class);

$app->delete('/dashboard', function(Request $request, Response $response ) {

  $response->getBody()->write("DELETING");
  return $response;

});
$app->put('/dashboard', function(Request $request, Response $response ) {

  $response->getBody()->write("ADDING");
  return $response;

});
$app->post('/dashboard', function(Request $request, Response $response ) {

  $response->getBody()->write("UPDATING");
  return $response;

});
```

**middleware.php**

```
use Slim\App;
use Slim\Middleware\ErrorMiddleware;
use Slim\Views\TwigMiddleware;
use Slim\Middleware\MethodOverrideMiddleware;

return function (App $app) {
  $app->addBodyParsingMiddleware();

  $app->add(TwigMiddleware::class);

  $app->addRoutingMiddleware();

  $app->add(new Slim\Middleware\MethodOverrideMiddleware);

  $app->add(ErrorMiddleware::class);
};
```

get('/dashboard', ...) displays a simple HTML:

```
  <form action="/dashboard" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="_METHOD" value="PUT"/>
       <button type="submit">Send PUT request</button>
   </form>
   <form action="/dashboard" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="_METHOD" value="DELETE"/>
       <button type="submit">Send DELETE request</button>
   </form>
```

Regardless which button I press, I got the Unexpected error:

```
POST header
```

Surprisingly, when I Chrome ARC to simulate PUT/DELETE requests, proper response is returned. I'm pulling my hairs out because of this. Can anybody show me what I did wrong and why my client (Chrome) is so stubborn?

Thank you in advance for any tip(s).

Comment: Test with only one of the two forms (or add different name attribute values to each of them like <form name="form1">...).

Comment: You could also var_dump $_POST and $_SERVER in your index.php file (before slim takes over) to see what actually arrives from the client.

Comment: Hi @lukas.j,
Indeed, when I removed one of the form, it started to work! Thank you good Sir.